# Android geolocation get Start and Stop coords Titanium

Tags: android, geolocation, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I have some problems with the locationhandler in my Android app.

Maybe someone can help me?

I get this error when i run it in my device:

> Message:  Uncaught error: addlistner only takes instances of Function.
>   The listner for event "Location" is "undefined"
>
> Source:  throw new Error('addListner only take instances of
>   function...

[Here is my code](http://lucyseven.com/gps.js)

Comment: Do you get a line number where this error occurs? Btw: I personally use the library from http://sourceforge.net/projects/libwlocate/ , its usage is way more simple than the Android-interface.

Comment: Yes i get 141, 10 .  I will look at the sourceforge lib. Thanx! :)

Comment: Line 141 contains a statement Ti.UI.createTextField() - don't know what "Ti" is but it seems there is a problem with your method to create this text field. It doesn't seem to be related to some Geolocation thingies.

Answer (score 0):

Richard, Please refer the following link [Geolocation can't get coords on Android Emulator](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/106441/geolocation-cant-get-coords-on-android-emulator)

Hope it helped you!!